# Problemas con formulario por ajax y paginaciones

Tags: php, ajax, msql, paginacion

Muy buenas, tengo esta aplicación https://vocabularioingles.gratis/basico hecha con PHP, MSQL y ajax. La aplicación funciona, pero únicamente la primera página de la paginación, a patir de la página dos, al enviar en formulario, en lugar de cargar el resultado por ajax, se refresca la página.

creo que el problema es por los parámetros de la url... pero no estoy seguro.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda :-)

Os comparto el código ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".formulario").bind("submit",function(){
        // Capturamnos el boton de envío
        var comprobar = $("#comprobar");
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: 'procesoAjax.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                /*
                * Esta función se ejecuta durante el envió de la petición al
                * servidor.
                * */
                // comprobar.text("Enviando"); Para button 
                comprobar.val("Enviando"); // Para input de tipo button
                comprobar.attr("disabled","disabled");
            },
            complete:function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta al termino de la petición
                * */
                comprobar.val("Comprobar");
                comprobar.removeAttr("disabled");
            },
            success: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta cuando termina la petición y esta ha sido
                * correcta
                * */
                $(".respuesta").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta si la peticón ha sido erronea
                * */
                alert("Problemas al tratar de enviar el formulario");
            }
        });
        // Nos permite cancelar el envio del formulario
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te falta:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Y un `return false` a la función que está en `bind('submit'`

Para que no se envíe el formulario

Quedaría algo así:

```
$(".formulario").bind("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // resto del código
    return false;
}
```

Saludos.